Can Cauchy's polyhedron rigidity theorem be generalized to affine transformations?

Conjecture: Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two convex realizations of an abstract polyhedron $P$. (In other words, $f(P)$ and $g(P)$ are two convex polyhedra whose face lattices are isomorphic.) Also suppose, for each face $x \in P$, there exists an affine transformation $h_x$ (not necessarily an isometry as in Cauchy's theorem) such that $h_x(f(x)) = g(x)$, and similarly $h_x(f(y)) = g(y)$ for every element $y < x$. Then there exists a single affine transformation $h_P$, such that $h_P(f(x)) = g(x)$ for every element $x \in P$.

Corollary: Cauchy's theorem.
Proof:
We only need to show that the affine transformation $h_P$ is in fact an isometry, given that its restriction to each face is an isometry.
I will conflate $P$ with $f(P)$.
Let $o \in P$ be a vertex, and let $a,b,c,d$ be four vertices adjacent to $o$, such that $oab,obc,ocd$ determine three faces. (The case where $o$ has only three adjacent vertices is easy.) Denote the edge vectors $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c,\vec d$ (with $o$ being the origin; i.e. we abbreviate $\vec{oa}=\vec a$). The three vectors $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ form a basis. Write the fourth edge vector
$$\vec d = x \,\vec a + y \,\vec b + z \,\vec c$$
for some scalars $x,y,z$. Then of course we have
$$\vec c\cdot\vec d = x \,\vec a\cdot\vec c + y \,\vec b\cdot\vec c + z \,\vec c\cdot\vec c.$$
Now apply the transformation:
$$h(\vec d) = x \,h(\vec a) + y \,h(\vec b) + z \,h(\vec c)$$
$$h(\vec c)\cdot h(\vec d) = x \,h(\vec a)\cdot h(\vec c) + y \,h(\vec b)\cdot h(\vec c) + z \,h(\vec c)\cdot h(\vec c).$$
By assumption, as $h$ is an isometry on the face $oab$, we have $|h(\vec a)| = |\vec a|$, and $|h(\vec b)| = |\vec b|$, and $h(\vec a)\cdot h(\vec b) = \vec a\cdot\vec b$. Similarly $h(\vec b)\cdot h(\vec c) = \vec b\cdot\vec c$ and $|h(\vec c)| = |\vec c|$ and $h(\vec c)\cdot h(\vec d) = \vec c\cdot\vec d$. Therefore
$$x \,h(\vec a)\cdot h(\vec c) + y \,h(\vec b)\cdot h(\vec c) + z \,h(\vec c)\cdot h(\vec c) = x \,\vec a\cdot\vec c + y \,\vec b\cdot\vec c + z \,\vec c\cdot\vec c,$$
that is, $x\,h(\vec a)\cdot h(\vec c) = x\,\vec a\cdot\vec c$. Since $d$ is not in the face $obc$, we have $x\neq0$, and thus $h(\vec a)\cdot h(\vec c)=\vec a\cdot\vec c$. We conclude that $h$ is an isometry, considering what it does to the basis vectors $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$.

this doesn't seem to be true for octahedra (with triangle faces - any 2 triangles are affine-equivalent) - e.g. their spatial diagonals don't always intersect in a single point

It was too good to be true....

Note that your condition on faces is automatically satisfied if polyhedra are simplicial. You can use this to find many counter-examples to your conjecture.

Still I feel like the Euclidean metric is perhaps too much structure. I wonder if there are generalizations similar to this one.
